# Can't load localhost in Chrome after enabling Intranet Browsing in IE10

Tags: google-chrome, xampp, localhost, internet-explorer-10, intranet

Just as the title says. I am using Xampp.

I was testing a local site in IE10 and it told me I needed to enable Intranet Browsing. So I did. I then went back to Chrome to test my local site and it won't load localhost anymore.

Is there a way I can have both loading locahost in harmony? Firefox works fine, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Enabling Intranet Browsing for IE10](http://www.sitepoint.com/enable-ie10-intranet-browsing/).

### Switch Off Enhanced Protected Mode

> Enhanced Protected Mode should not be enabled by default; it uses 64-bit content processes and disables various controls. If necessary, switch it off in the Cog/Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security section [...]

then:

> Assuming you’ve enabled intranet browsing, click the Security tab followed by the “Local intranet” icon. Ensure “Enable Protected Mode” is unchecked [...]

### Configure Your Intranet Mode

#### Add Local Addresses

If the automatic detection of local addresses doesn't work, manually add the local addresses that should be part of your intranet network (so, for you, `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, etc... Feels silly, eh?

#### Disable the Compatibility View

> By default, IE enables Compatibility View for all local and intranet sites. Your lovingly-crafted pages will render in IE7 mode as if it were 2006 again. To disable this option, you must either enable the Menu bar (right-click an empty part of IE’s toolbar) or hold down Alt. Select Tools > Compatibility View Settings [...]
>
> Uncheck “Display intranet sites in Compatibility View” and hit Close. Your local sites should display in IE10 mode on both the desktop and Metro views.

---

*Yeah, that seems perfectly normal to have to do this for some security reasons, no worries there!*

Comment: Everything is as you said. Still the problem. I had fixed this before, I don't remember how. I don't think I even did anything in particular it just started working again and just the same, it has stopped working by itself. What I was doing before this happened was testing logging in with wp_signon in internet explorer. I switched back over to chrome, can't load localhost (any sites). Firefox loads it fine.

Comment: Ok.... what had happened was, IE put itself into quirks mode somehow, which broke Chrome.

Comment: My god IE is crap. Why is chrome so tied into IE?